# convert large integer/float to string using PHP

Tags: php

I want to convert a large integer/float number to a string, it may has no sense but i saw that in a problem solving exam.

My question is so simple,

Why this code returns `14226520737620289536` instead of `14226520737620288370` ?

```
echo sprintf('%0.0f',14226520737620288370);
```

Comment: To start, `14226520737620288370` isn't a float, it's n integer; and it's outside of valid integer range for 32-bit or 64-bit PHP

Comment: PHP uses a float to internally store your large number because 32-bit integer is not large enought, before it even is formatted with your sprintf, and float has no exact integer precision at that range

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902817/convert-float-to-plain-string-representation

Comment: sorry, i fixed the question to integer

Comment: Weird...`echo sprintf('%0.0f',14226520737620283);` prints `14226520737620284`