# Converting float to string without exponential notation

Tags: php, bcmath

I'm looking for a way to convert a float value to string in PHP without exponential (scientific) notation. I need it in order to use [bcmath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php), which doesn't support exponential notation.

```
<?php

$float  = 0.000003;
$string = (string) $float;

var_dump($string); 
// Actual result: "3.0E-6"
// Expected result: "0.000003"

var_dump(bcadd($string, $string, 6)); 
// Actual result: 0.000000 
// Expected result: "0.000006"
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902817/convert-float-to-plain-string-representation) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. number_format looks like what I'm looking for. A bit hacky, but does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sprintf`

```
$float  = 0.000003;
$string = sprintf("%.6f", $float);

var_dump($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
   function f2s(float $f) {
        $s = (string)$f;
        if (!strpos($s,"E")) return $s;
        list($be,$ae)= explode("E",$s);
        $fs = "%.".(string)(strlen(explode(".",$be)[1])+(abs($ae)-1))."f";
        return sprintf($fs,$f); 
    }
```